# How to keep music playing when screensaver goes on?

Tags: sound, music, screensaver, spotify

I'm always playing music on Spotify. It works fine, but when I don't do anything for 15 minutes and the screensaver/powersave mode kicks in the music stops playing. This is extremely annoying, and the single reason why my girlfriend hates my Ubuntu laptop.

Is there any good solution to this  (except for making the screen stay on forever)?

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and I installed Spotify using the snap package (`snap install spotify`).

Comment: Do you have premium? Maybe it's stopping because a limitation of the free account.

Comment: @davidbaumann - No I've got a premium account. On my macbook it keeps on playing when it goes into sleep/screensaver mode.

Comment: I recently installed xubuntu and installed Spotify with normal apt-get. I have the same experience, when I lock the screen the audio goes. Also, spotify seem to prevent the screen from locking.